# Awkward syntax of generic method with generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, units-of-measurement

I am trying to create a units of measurement class library.

What I have so far is:

```
public abstract class UnitBase
{
    protected double unitValue;
    protected readonly double toSiFactor;
    //more stuff goes here
}

//Meters, feet, miles etc will derive from this
public class LengthUnit : UnitBase
{
    //various methods and operator overloading

    //Among others there is To<> for conversions, not really needed
    //to understand the problem but relevant.
    public L To<L>() where L : LengthUnit, new()
    {
        L converted = new L();
        converted.FromSi(ToSi());  //ToSi() and FromSi() are in UnitBase, omitted for brevity
        return converted;
    }
}

//Seconds Hours etc will derive from this
public class TimeUnit : UnitBase
{
    //Add() Subtract methods and various operator overloading
}
```

So far so good. But now I want to create complex unit types such as speed. So here it is:

```
public class SpeedUnit<S, T> : UnitBase
    where S : LengthUnit, new()
    where T : TimeUnit, new()
{
    //=======================
    //HERE IS THE AWKWARDNESS
    //=======================
    public U To<U, S1, T1>()
        where U : SpeedUnit<S1, T1>, new()
        where S1 : LengthUnit, new()
        where T1 : TimeUnit, new()
    {
        U converted = new U();
        converted.FromSi(ToSi());
        return converted;
    }
}

public class Knots : SpeedUnit<NauticalMiles, Hours>
{
    //omitted code
}

public class FeetPerMinute : SpeedUnit<Feet, Minutes>
{
    //omitted code
}
```

So here is my problem: Suppose that you have Knots and you want to convert them to `FeetPerMinute`. What would be ideal is:

```
Knots kts = new Knots(20);
FeetPerMinute = kts.To<FeetPerMinute>();
```

Instead I have to do:

```
FeetPerMinute = kts.To<FeetPerMinute, Feet, Minutes>();
```

That's a little bit awkward and can get event worse when it comes to even more complex types such as forces. `To()` will be something like:

```
Newtons n = someForce.To<Newtons, Kilograms, Meters, Seconds>()
```

Or even worst if you make the mistake to use an Acceleration type:

```
Newtons n = someForce.To<Newtons, Kilograms, Acceleration<Meters, Seconds>, Meters, Seconds>()
```

Not really handy especially if you have simplicity in mind.
So my questions are:

- Is there any way to make this work? (besides removing generic parameters from `SpeedUnit`)
- Why can't the notorious type inference of the compiler work to spot that `Meters` and `Seconds` are already there in `MetersPerSecond`?

Comment: What about a `static From<U, S1, T1>(U value)`?

Comment: @OndrejTucny Ah no I'm afraid that won't work: What's the return type of `From`? `U`? Or some other type `U1`? Don't forget I want to convert from `Knots` (`U`) to `FeetPerMinute` (`U1`).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that C# does not allow to infer generic types from other generic types, only from parameters. You could also say the generic type restrictions are not exppressive enough for this.

However, I don't really see why you even represent different units as different classes? My personal advice would be to use structs for each physical dimension - not unit. So, have a struct like this:

```
public struct Length {
    public static Length FromMeters(double meters) {
        // ...
    }

    public double InMiles() { ... }

    // operator overloads
}
```

This way you don't have any problems with generics and you don't even have a runtime impact but still have compile-time support.

Assume you have structs `Length`, `Time` and `Speed`, then you can easily overload operators that allow you to divide a `Length` by a `Time` and get a `Speed` as result. You can then query the value of the speed in whatever unit you like through a method (of speed) as e.g. `InMilesPerSecond` returning a double.

**Edit:**
I guess that the real problem in you original idea is a problem of wrong abstractions. In particular, a speed is not (in the sense of an identity) a length divided by a time, although you can express it that way. This is fine and subtle difference. For instance, you can express 1W = 1Nm or 1W = 1VA. Thus, you should not model PowerType, Length> because this is not the identity of power but only a way of calculating it.

Comment: I have created a request on uservoice some time ago for this: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3418197-make-it-possible-to-infer-generic-type-arguments

Comment: _However, I don't really see why you even represent different units as different classes?_ — in order to prevent any future Mars landers from crashing by confusing miles represented as `double` with kilometers represented as the very same `double`? :-)

Comment: @OndrejTucny There are much better ways to save Mars explorers, in particular the solution that I just proposed, except that my version has no runtime impact where memory is a valuable and limited resource on a Mars explorer. With the structs, you can still overload operators, the ToMiles is just when you in the end convert your Length construct to double

Comment: From a performance perspective in an embedded system I do agree. However, for general-purpose use the approach explored by the OP seems very legit (and I don't care whether he uses classes or structs at this stage).

Comment: @OndrejTucny In the approach of the OP you cannot use structs as they do not support inheritance for a very good reason.

Comment: @Georg That's a good point with Watts. Never thought of it. But what's another way of defining speed besides S/t? For my case I find it very appealing to be able to multiply `SpeedUnit` to `TimeUnit` and get a `LengthUnit` back (of specific type since `SpeedUnit` is generic).